# Implement Base64VideoField Django REST

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, base64

I need to `POST` a binary file to my system. To do that I have to convert it to be `base64`.  I have seen [example](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields) parsing `pdf` file to the system already and believe that `mp4` should not be a big different.

**My attempts:**
1. Check with `Base64ImageField`

```py
class Base64ImageField(Base64FieldMixin, ImageField):
    """
    A django-rest-framework field for handling image-uploads through raw post data.
    It uses base64 for en-/decoding the contents of the file.
    """
    ALLOWED_TYPES = (
        "jpeg",
        "jpg",
        "png",
        "gif"
    )
    INVALID_FILE_MESSAGE = _("Please upload a valid image.")
    INVALID_TYPE_MESSAGE = _("The type of the image couldn't be determined.")

    def get_file_extension(self, filename, decoded_file):
        extension = imghdr.what(filename, decoded_file)
        extension = "jpg" if extension == "jpeg" else extension
        return extension
```

`imghdr` is very handy, but unfortunately it is designed for image

2. Check python official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/mm.html). Not found `video` type
3. Check `opencv` . It shows me the ability to open, but I want just check the extension. Although `opencv` be able to play that file. It does not mean it is a supported extension for web browser.

**As is:**

```py
class Base64VideoField(Base64FileField):
    ALLOWED_TYPES = ['mp4', ]

    def get_file_extension(self, filename, decoded_file):
        # TODO: Do something that validate the user input!
        return 'mp4'
```

**Question:**
How to correctly implement `Base64VideoField`?

Comment: Why do you think you have to encode the file?

Comment: @KlausD. Android developer has a hard time to `POST` blob to server. But it has `base64` for this issue.

Comment: You might have confused the encoding of the data to transfer with the transfer encoding. If you pre-encode it, it will be double encoded.

Comment: Yes. I am doing double encoded. It might be easier to deal with base64 string rather than blob when developing with javascript. Am I going wrong way?

Comment: Now. I have an evidence proof. Double encoding dramatically slow UX down. Thank you very much for you comment. @KlausD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Base64FileField](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields#base64filefield) from the same library and update ALLOWED_TYPES for video files.

Comment: Yes. I did. And end up with input signature `filename` in `get_file_extension` become random string. And that's my question.